# Drawing Bitmap with unsafe per pixel access results in empty image

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, bitmap, gdi+

I have a class that creates a matrix of `Color` values by reading a `Bitmap`. The class directly reads each byte in the pixels inside an `unsafe` block using the pointer to the image. The purpose of the class is to read the pixel values into memory where I can run filters on them before saving the image as a new file.

I can recreate the image using **GDI+**'s setPixel() method, however it is too slow for my needs.

I am attempting to save a new image file using the following function:

```
    public void saveImageFromPixels()
    {

        this.newBitmap = new Bitmap(srcBitmap.Width, srcBitmap.Height);

        BitmapData imgData = newBitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, newBitmap.Width, newBitmap.Height),
                                                ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
                                                PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

        int stride = imgData.Stride;
        System.IntPtr Scan0 = imgData.Scan0;

        unsafe
        {
            byte* p = (byte*)(void*)Scan0;
            int nOffset = stride - newBitmap.Width * 3;

            for (int x = 0; x < newBitmap.Height; ++x)
            {

                for (int y = 0; y < newBitmap.Width; ++y)
                {
                    p[0] = (byte)(255 - matrix[y][x].B);
                    p[1] = (byte)(255 - matrix[y][x].G);
                    p[2] = (byte)(255 - matrix[y][x].R);
                    p += 3;
                }
                p += nOffset;
            }


        }

        this.newBitmap.Save(@"C:\images\1-d.jpg");
    }
```

However the result is an empty image (with the proper dimensions). The code that directly accesses the pixels and saves the value as a `Color` works fine, it is just saving the image I am having problems with.

The following code defines `srcBitmap` and `newBitmap`

```
    private Bitmap srcBitmap;
    private Bitmap newBitmap;
    private List<List<Color>> matrix;

    public PixelMatrix(string path)
    {

        this.srcBitmap = new Bitmap(path);

        this.matrix = new List<List<Color>>(srcBitmap.Width);

        for (int x = 0; x < srcBitmap.Width; x++)
        {
            this.matrix.Add(new List<Color>(srcBitmap.Height));
        }

    }
```

Comment: Yes, UnlockBits.  Also note that you are saving a PNG, not a JPEG.  And use the Bitmap(int, int, PixelFormat) constructor.  And use x to iterate Width, not Height.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the constructor, the iterator is going to be fixed... this was just a quick hack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to `UnlockBits()`.